# How identify the selected frame in java?

Tags: java, jframe

because I am displaying multiple images in my java programm, each image into a new jframe.
I need to identify the selected jframe in oder to make changes on the displayed image and show it in the same jframe.

So, How could I recognize the last selected jframe ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you to use some other layout such as [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to share same display space for multiple panel instead of using multiple `JFrame`.

See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)

---

If you want to stick with current approach then create a global static reference of type `JFrame` to keep the reference of selected `JFrame`.

Use `FocusListener` to keep track of the selected `JFarme`

> So, How could I recognize the last selected jframe ?

Keep the references of all opened `JFrame` and iterate all to check for `JFrame#isFocused()` or `JFrame#isActive()`

Comment: I'd prefer creating a class that implements WindowAdapter (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html) and keeps track of the active frame through event callbacks over iterating over the list of frames to find the active one.